# How to use vendor file/class in codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a codeigniter project named **ciapp** and the path of this project is **fgtsmsporta.com/ciapp/**. There is another directory at same domain for send sms, path is **fgtsmsporta.com/code/buzzsms/vendor/smsgopil.php**

normally i use smsgopil.php for use in core such as:

```
$v=SMS($number,$msg);
$v->sendmsg();
```

Now i cann't understand how to use smsgopil.php in my codeigniter project(ciapp).

Comment: Place it in your plugin directory and load it in controller or you can make a new library file with same code and load as library and call the functions

Comment: but that file exist at same domain. So, can we use that without place?

Comment: But it is outside of ci root folder. So you need to include it inside root folder.